# CrystalDecisions.Web DLL

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I've downloaded the Business Objects 3.0 SDK but it didn't contain the CrystalDecisions.Web DLL (version 12).

The DLL exists on the Business Objects XI SDK (version 11.5) and on the Business Objects 4.0 SDK (version 13), but not on the BO3

Any thoughts  on the matter?

Thanks

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to accomplish?  There might be an alternate solution.

Comment: Im migrating an application from BOXI to BO3 and it uses that dll. I dont have access to the people who built it so I dont know if there is a work around.

Comment: What does the application do?  Create an InfoView-like portal?  Schedule reports?  Modify reports?  What specific functionality is provided by this DLL?  I've done a fair amount of work w/ the SDK and I'm not familiar w/ it.

Comment: it does pretty much the same CMC does. This specific dll displays the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '[CrystalDecisions.Web DLLs version 12.0.2000.0](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1721662)' thread on SAP's forum might be useful--it discusses service packs.

You may also want to leverage the [OpenDocument SDK](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4_opendocument_en.pdf) to do the 'heavy lifting' for displaying a report rather than trying to code it yourself.

You might also consider migrating to the WebServices SDK as well.